# What is the '$p$-completion of a spectrum'?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, definition, p-adic-number-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

Suppose I have a finite pointed CW complex X and an integer $n$. In the context of stable homotopy theory this is known as a finite spectrum. For a given prime $p$, something called the *$p$-completion $X_p$* of $(X,n)$ is referred to in the following [paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/ON-FREYD%27S-GENERATING-HYPOTHESIS-Hovey/9c9a1017acf6b16f419bca8400f386deccf4e83c). ("Let $X_p$ be the $p$-completion of a spectrum $X$" at the top of the second page.)

How is this defined exactly? Does it have a well-established meaning in topology? I cannot find anything that explains this adequately.

Comment: It is usually referring to the localisation with respect to Moore spectrum $S(\mathbb{Z}/p)$.  See e.g. [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362981/) and [Bousfield's original paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(79)90018-1).

Comment: This is maybe addressed in may's "more concise algebraic topology"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained thoroughly in Chapter 9 of *Spectra and the Steenrod Algebra* by Margolis. In particular, a $p$-completion of a spectrum $X$ is defined to be a map $f: X \to Y$ such that $\pi_* f: \pi_* X \to \pi_* Y$ gives the $p$-completion of the homotopy groups of $X$. Margolis notes that this need not exist in general, but it does if you assume that for each $n$, $\pi_n X$ is a finitely generated abelian group. Call such an $X$ "finite type". (This is Theorem 1 in Chapter 9.) Combining Proposition 9 and Theorem 11 gives: if $X$ is the $p$-localization of a finite-type spectrum, then its $p$-completion may be obtained as Bousfield localization with respect to the Moore spectrum $S(\mathbb{Z}/p)$ (as @user10354138 said).